# PERFORMANCE Is it good to cache sessions in Cake PHP?

Tags: cakephp, caching

On my website I have this query running on every page.

```
SELECT `Session`.`id`, `Session`.`data`, `Session`.`expires` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 'someid' LIMIT 1
```

I am thinking to cache this query, so basically I am planning to do the following:

```
if(not cached)

    run and cache query

else

    get cached data
    if(session is expired)

        create new session and cache it, delete old cache
```

So is this the right thing to do? I am thinking to implement cache on sessions. Will it increase the performance?

Comment: How about simply trying it? Personally I'd doubt that there's much room for improvements (given that there is an open DB connection anyways), especially with DBMS that are offloading parts of the data, or maybe even everything into memory. Such questions highly depend on your environment, and are mostly of theoretical nature, and therefore not overly suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @ndm ok. i will test and post results here, just wanted to confirm that its not bad practice to cache sessions

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misconception what it means to "cache" the session. In cakePHP you can simply write the [sessions to a cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) like "APC, memcache, or Xcache" which might improve your performance.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cache',
    'handler' => array(
        'config' => 'session'
    )
));
```

Comment: I am using this configuration `'defaults' => 'database'`, the thing is I want to make my sessions persistant, so can't use your configuration...

Comment: You could check out redis. It's fast and can be run in a persistent way.